# How can I get the name of the current selected datagridview when I’ve multiple datagridviews in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 5 datagridviews and I want to get details from the selected datagridview.
Like when selecting the gridview row, I want to take that row details with the gridview name.

```
private void assigncontrctbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
        SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        newCmd.Connection = conn;
        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();
        string hh = "SELECT contractstatus from dbo.contracts where "here i need gridview name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(hh, conn);
        string dd = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if ((dd == "Contract logged") && (cmbCategory.Text != "Calculate Contract") && (cmbCategory.Text == "Verify Contract"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no");
        }
        else if ((dd == "Calculate Contract") && (cmbCategory.Text != "Verify Contract") && (cmbCategory.Text == "Calculate Contract"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("verify");
        }

        else
        {
            if (dba.logcontract(cntrctnmecmb.Text, Convert.ToInt32(prcecodecmb.Text), seasoncmb.Text, cmplexitycmb.Text, revisecmb.Text, logdatetime, condatefrm.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), condteto.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), vatcmb.Text, statuscmb.Text, lstcmnt.Text, apprvedbycmb.Text, cmbCategory.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Added");
                FillGridCal();
                FillGridVer();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried?
Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before.

Comment: i just need to get selected gridview name for a where condition in my query

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: i have edited the question please help

Comment: have you successfully filled your datagrids with data?

Comment: I can't understand. DataGridView has a property Name inherited from Control. Seehttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, grid views have data and I also exchange data with in gridviews. but i have to specifically mention selected gridview data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an an event say `CellClick` for each of your DataGridView. When a row is clicked, you can get the details that you want. I'm assuming that what you mean by `take that row details` is `take the cell values for the selected row`.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        string firstColumn = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[firstColumn.Name].Value;//I'm getting 1 column from the selected row, you can do a loop if you want to get all cells
        string dataGridView = dgv.Name;//This is the DataGridView name
    }
```